# PHP Class Variable Declaration with Assignment Failing

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm quite new to PHP Classes and I'm currently setting up a couple of Class Variables as shown below. The .time() function fails - third line below. If I remove the .time() it works.

```
class session {

  private $variable;
  private $cookieExpiry = time() + 15811200;      // Cookie Expire

  function __construct() {
```

Are you not allowed to set a variable like this with a default php function?

Is there a way to do this?

thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties are a blueprint and must be independent of the runtime environment. You can set them to literal values but you can't make function calls like that. Set the initial properties in the constructor:

```
class session {

  private $variable;
  private $cookieExpiry;

  function __construct() {
      $this->cookieExpiry = time() + 15811200; // Cookie Expire
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 I'll give you this one, I think you beat me by like 5 seconds :)